# Programming webcam on Linux

Tags: linux, webcam

I want to be able to capture images from a webcam on Linux. This is still a project requirement and I'm having a difficulty finding up-to-date information about capturing images from a webcam on Linux. Is it true that every webcam has different API (unlike the Windows variant where I can use a common API), so I must write the program for a specific webcam?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webcams on Linux are accessed through the [Video4Linux](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) API, which is common across all camera models.

There are plenty of existing [framegrabbers for webcams](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/framegrabbers.html) that use this API - you could look at these for ideas, or just one as-is.